# Create custom installer as assembly

Tags: installation, windows-installer, .net-assembly

Is there any example to create custom installer (not windows installer), which add assemblies to GAC, Program Files and shortcuts to Start->programs?
I need .net assembly to put it on IIS server for execution only. I want to restrict some administrators who can run that assembly (run means install) but not copy it.

Best regards
Krzysztof

Answer (score 1):

An installation program at it's core is just a computer program like any other computer program.  It is completely possible to write an installer in the programming language of your choice.  You could write a VBSCript or PowerShell script that creates directories, copy files, creates shortcuts, calls GACUTIL or Fusion  to register an assembly in the GAC.

But why?

The point of using Windows Installer or other domain specific language is that they have already provided implementations of these common use cases.  This allows you to focus on the what and not the how.  Declarative vs imperative programming.

Generally if you have a DRM concern it's best to handle that in the application itself.  Enable people to install the application but during a first run handle license validation and activation needs.